# save syntax with loop in python possible?

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to create a lot of widgets in tkinter. I am currently using a lot of code for this. Is there a way to summarise the code? However, I would still like to be able to capture the value of each widgets.
The numbering goes up to 200...
Thanks a lot!

'''

```
    self.A1_access_measure_calculation = tk.IntVar()
    self.A1_access_measure = tk.Checkbutton(self.A_Frame_measure, text="A1", variable=self.A1_access_measure_calculation)
    self.A1_access_measure.grid(row =2, column =0, sticky = "W",padx=25, pady=4) 
    self.A1_access_measure.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', lambda A1: self.enable_measure_specification("A1"))
    
    self.A2_access_measure_calculation = tk.IntVar()
    self.A2_access_measure = tk.Checkbutton(self.A_Frame_measure, text="A2", variable=self.A2_access_measure_calculation)
    self.A2_access_measure.grid(row =3, column =0, sticky = "W",padx=25, pady=4) 
    self.A2_access_measure.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', lambda A2: self.enable_measure_specification("A2"))

    self.A3_access_measure_calculation = tk.IntVar()
    self.A3_access_measure = tk.Checkbutton(self.A_Frame_measure, text="A3", variable=self.A3_access_measure_calculation)
    self.A3_access_measure.grid(row =4, column =0, sticky = "W",padx=25, pady=4) 
    self.A3_access_measure.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', lambda A3: self.enable_measure_specification("A3"))

    self.A4_access_measure_calculation = tk.IntVar()
    self.A4_access_measure = tk.Checkbutton(self.A_Frame_measure, text="A4", variable=self.A4_access_measure_calculation)
    self.A4_access_measure.grid(row =5, column =0, sticky = "W",padx=25, pady=4) 
    self.A4_access_measure.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', lambda A4: self.enable_measure_specification("A4"))
    
    self.A5_access_measure_calculation = tk.IntVar()
    self.A5_access_measure = tk.Checkbutton(self.A_Frame_measure, text="A5", variable=self.A5_access_measure_calculation)
    self.A5_access_measure.grid(row =6, column =0, sticky = "W",padx=25, pady=4) 
    self.A5_access_measure.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', lambda A5: self.enable_measure_specification("A5"))
```

'''

I would also like to summarise the If conditions.

'''

```
    if self.calculations["A1"].get() == 0 and event_measure == "A1":
        self.A1_Menu_blade_exchange.grid(row =2, column = 1, padx=3, pady=1, sticky = "W")
        self.A1_Menu_rubbing_marks.grid(row =2, column = 2, padx=3, pady=1, sticky = "W")

    if self.calculations["A1"].get() == 1 and event_measure == "A1":
        self.A1_Menu_blade_exchange.grid_forget()
        self.A1_Menu_rubbing_marks.grid_forget()
        self.A1_Menu_rubbing_marks_border.grid_forget()
        self.A1_blade_exchange_Type.set('')
        self.A1_rubbing_marks_Type.set('')
        self.A1_rubbing_marks_border_Type.set('')

    if self.calculations["A2"].get() == 0 and event_measure == "A2":
        self.A2_Menu_blade_exchange.grid(row =3, column = 1, padx=3, pady=1, sticky = "W")
        self.A2_Menu_rubbing_marks.grid(row =3, column = 2, padx=3, pady=1, sticky = "W")

    if self.calculations["A2"].get() == 1 and event_measure == "A2":
        self.A2_Menu_blade_exchange.grid_forget()
        self.A2_Menu_rubbing_marks.grid_forget()
        self.A2_Menu_rubbing_marks_border.grid_forget()
        self.A2_blade_exchange_Type.set('')
        self.A2_rubbing_marks_Type.set('')
        self.A2_rubbing_marks_border_Type.set('')
```

'''

Answer (score 2):

Instead of individual variables for each `IntVar` and `CheckButton`, define a `dict` to hold each set.

```
import functools  # Used later; see below


keys = [f"A{i}" for i in range(1, 200)]
self.calculations = {k: tk.IntVar() for k in keys}
self.access_measures = {k: tk.Checkbutton(self.A_Frame_measure, text=k, variable=self.calculations[k]) for k in keys}
```

You can then iterate over the `access_measures` dictionary to call `grid` and `bind` on each with the appropriate arguments. Most of the arguments to `grid` are constant, except for the `row` value which can be computed by `enumerate`.
The tricky part is making sure the callback passed to `bind` actually has the current value of `k` to pass to `enable_measure_specification`.

```
for r, (k, cb) in enumerate(self.access_measures.items(), start=2):
    cb.grid(row=r, column=0, sticky="W", padx=25, pady=4)
    cb.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', functools.partial(self.enable_measure_specification, k))
```

Comment: That looks good, but i got following issue: NameError: name 'functools' is not defined

Comment: It's a module in the standard library; you need to import it first.

Comment: Very good. But one last thing: When I want to call up the value (self.A1_access_measure_calculation.get() == 0), I get the following error message: AttributeError: 'Win1' object has no attribute 'A1_access_measure_calculation'

Comment: Because you don't have any attributes with such names anymore. You have a single `dict` with `"A1"`, etc as keys: `self.calculations["A1"].get() == 0`.

Comment: Very nice of you. Do you have any advice for me on how to summarise the If conditions? (I have inserted this in my question above)

Comment: That should be posted as a new question, not an addition to an answered question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65686535/summarise-code-in-python-with-many-if-clauses

Comment: I have tried to transfer your style to my OptionMenu. However, I get many error messages. Can you possibly help me again? Thank you very much for your help! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65690937/how-to-use-loop-to-reduce-the-the-code-in-python