# summarise code in python with many if-clauses

Tags: python, tkinter

I am currently using a lot of code for this. Is there a way to summarise the code? Thanks a lot!

I would like to summarise the If conditions.

'''

```
if self.calculations["A1"].get() == 0 and event_measure == "A1":
    self.Menu_blade_exchange["A1"].grid(row =2, column = 1, padx=3, pady=1, sticky = "W")
    self.Menu_rubbing_marks["A1"].grid(row =2, column = 2, padx=3, pady=1, sticky = "W")

if self.calculations["A1"].get() == 1 and event_measure == "A1":
    self.Menu_blade_exchange["A1"].grid_forget()
    self.Menu_rubbing_marks["A1"].grid_forget()
    self.Menu_rubbing_marks_border["A1"].grid_forget()
    self.blade_exchange_Type["A1"].set('')
    self.rubbing_marks_Type["A1"].set('')
    self.rubbing_marks_border_Type["A1"].set('')

if self.calculations["A2"].get() == 0 and event_measure == "A2":
    self.Menu_blade_exchange["A2"].grid(row =3, column = 1, padx=3, pady=1, sticky = "W")
    self.Menu_rubbing_marks["A2"].grid(row =3, column = 2, padx=3, pady=1, sticky = "W")

if self.calculations["A2"].get() == 1 and event_measure == "A2":
    self.Menu_blade_exchange["A2"].grid_forget()
    self.Menu_rubbing_marks["A2"].grid_forget()
    self.Menu_rubbing_marks_border["A2"].grid_forget()
    self.blade_exchange_Type["A2"].set('')
    self.rubbing_marks_Type["A2"].set('')
    self.rubbing_marks_border_Type["A2"].set('')
```

....
'''

Comment: The fact that you have instance-variables with consecutive names like `self.A1_Menu...` and `self.A2_Menu...` suggests that these things should really be in a collection, like a list or dictionary.

Comment: Which is what I already suggested in the answer to your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65672150/save-syntax-with-loop-in-python-possible/65672384?noredirect=1#comment116137567_65672384).

Comment: Yes, i corrected the post now. @chepner

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to understand what you are trying to accomplish since you didn't provide a complete example. If we can assume that each block of code is identical and the only thing that is changing is the index into the array, you might be able to replace all of the `if` statements with a single block of code:

```
if self.calculations[event_measure].get() == 0:
    self.Menu_blade_exchange[event_measure].grid(row =2, column = 1, padx=3, pady=1, sticky = "W")
    self.Menu_rubbing_marks[event_measure].grid(row =2, column = 2, padx=3, pady=1, sticky = "W")

else:
    self.Menu_blade_exchange[event_measure].grid_forget()
    self.Menu_rubbing_marks[event_measure].grid_forget()
    self.Menu_rubbing_marks_border[event_measure].grid_forget()
    self.blade_exchange_Type[event_measure].set('')
    self.rubbing_marks_Type[event_measure].set('')
    self.rubbing_marks_border_Type[event_measure].set('')
```

In the comments someone pointed out that the row numbers change, which could be solved by saving the row numbers in an array as well

```
rownum = {"A1": 2, "A2": 3, ...}
...
if self.calculations[event_measure].get() == 0:
    self.Menu_blade_exchange[event_measure].grid(row =rownum[event_measure], column = 1, padx=3, pady=1, sticky = "W")
    self.Menu_rubbing_marks[event_measure].grid(row =rownum[event_measure], column = 2, padx=3, pady=1, sticky = "W")
```

Another solution might be to use `grid_remove` rather than `grid_forget`, so that all of the configuration options are remembered.

This would likely be much, much easier if each "event measure" was an instance of a class.

Comment: The `row` keyword-argument to `grid` is also changing.

Comment: @PaulM.: thanks for pointing that out. That could easily be solved by saving the row numbers in an array. Though, I'm guessing there are better ways to solve that. I'll update my answer to mention the row.