# how to use loop to reduce the the code in python

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to create a lot of widgets in tkinter. I am currently using a lot of code for this. Is there a way to summarise the code? However, I would still like to be able to capture the value of each widgets. The numbering goes up to 200... Thanks a lot!

'''

```
    self.A1_rubbing_marks_Type = tk.StringVar(self.A_Frame_measure)
    # Dictionary with options
    self.A1_choice_rubbing_marks=  ['No', 'Yes']
    self.A1_rubbing_marks_Type.set('') # set the default option
    self.A1_Menu_rubbing_marks = tk.OptionMenu(self.A_Frame_measure, self.A1_rubbing_marks_Type, *self.A1_choice_rubbing_marks, command=self.show_rubbing_marks_borders)
    self.A1_Menu_rubbing_marks.config(width=4)    
    self.A1_Menu_rubbing_marks.grid_forget()

    self.A2_rubbing_marks_Type = tk.StringVar(self.A_Frame_measure)
    # Dictionary with options
    self.A2_choice_rubbing_marks=  ['No', 'Yes']
    self.A2_rubbing_marks_Type.set('') # set the default option
    self.A2_Menu_rubbing_marks = tk.OptionMenu(self.A_Frame_measure, self.A2_rubbing_marks_Type, *self.A2_choice_rubbing_marks, command=self.show_rubbing_marks_borders)
    self.A2_Menu_rubbing_marks.config(width=4)    
    self.A2_Menu_rubbing_marks.grid_forget()

    self.A3_rubbing_marks_Type = tk.StringVar(self.A_Frame_measure)
    # Dictionary with options
    self.A3_choice_rubbing_marks=  ['No', 'Yes']
    self.A3_rubbing_marks_Type.set('') # set the default option
    self.A3_Menu_rubbing_marks = tk.OptionMenu(self.A_Frame_measure, self.A3_rubbing_marks_Type, *self.A3_choice_rubbing_marks, command=self.show_rubbing_marks_borders)
    self.A3_Menu_rubbing_marks.config(width=4)    
    self.A3_Menu_rubbing_marks.grid_forget()

    self.A4_rubbing_marks_Type = tk.StringVar(self.A_Frame_measure)
    # Dictionary with options
    self.A4_choice_rubbing_marks=  ['No', 'Yes']
    self.A4_rubbing_marks_Type.set('') # set the default option
    self.A4_Menu_rubbing_marks = tk.OptionMenu(self.A_Frame_measure, self.A4_rubbing_marks_Type, *self.A4_choice_rubbing_marks, command=self.show_rubbing_marks_borders)
    self.A4_Menu_rubbing_marks.config(width=4)    
    self.A4_Menu_rubbing_marks.grid_forget()
```

'''

I defined a dict, but i get too much issues.

'''

```
    keys_blade_exchange_Type = [f"A{i}" for i in range(1, 200)]
    self.blade_exchange_Type = {k_2: tk.StringVar(self.A_Frame_measure) for k_2 in keys_blade_exchange_Type}
    self.choice_blade_exchange =  ['No', 'Yes']
    self.Menu_blade_exchange = {k_2: tk.OptionMenu(self.A_Frame_measure, *self.choice_blade_exchange ,  self.blade_exchange_Type[k_2]) for k_2 in keys_blade_exchange_Type}

    for r, (k_2, cb_2) in enumerate(self.Menu_blade_exchange.items(), start=2):
        cb_2.grid(row=r, column=1, sticky="W", padx=25, pady=4)
```

'''

Comment: Not sure if this will work, but try creating a list with all the `self.Ax` variables in it then iterate through it and do everything you need to.

Comment: Yes, it's a good idea but i tried a lot but i have not made it so far.

Comment: What does "too much issues" mean? That's too vague to be of any use.

Comment: I would think making a function to create these objects would be the best idea since they are essentially the same

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple loop, `setattr` and `getattr`.

```
for i in range(1, 201):
    setattr(self, f'A{i}__rubbing_marks_Type',  tk.StringVar(self.A_Frame_measure))
    setattr(self, f'A{i}_choice_rubbing_marks',  ['No', 'Yes'])
    getattr(self, f'A{i}_rubbing_marks_Type').set('')
    setattr(self, f'A{i}_Menu_rubbing_marks',
            tk.OptionMenu(self.A_Frame_measure, 
                          getattr(self, f'A{i}_rubbing_marks_Type'), 
                          *getattr(self, f'A{i}_choice_rubbing_marks'), 
                          command=self.show_rubbing_marks_borders))
    getattr(self, f'A{i}_Menu_rubbing_marks').config(width=4)    
    getattr(self, f'A{i}_Menu_rubbing_marks').grid_forget()
```

If `f-strings` are not available in the version of Python you are using, simply replace them with `.format(i)`.

Comment: i got following issue: SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: @Djangopy See updated answer, I misplaced a `'`

Comment: This will make the code very difficult to debug.

Comment: This may reduce the lines of code but this is horrible and should not be used in any meaningful project

Answer (score 0):

Remove the prefix from your variables, and then create dictionaries instead with the prefix as the key.

For example, `self.A1_choice_rubbing_marks` becomes `self.choice_rubbing_marks["A1"]`, etc.

Do that for each variable. Don't try to use dictionary comprehensions until you figure out how to do it with simple loops.

For example:

```
self.choice_rubbing_marks = {}
self.rubbing_marks_Type = {}
self.Menu_rubbing_marks = {}
self.Frame_measure = {}

for i in range(200):
    key = f"A{i}"  # => A0, A1, ..., A199
    self.rubbing_marks_Type[key] = tk.StringVar(self.A_Frame_measurevalue='')
    self.Frame_measure[key] = tk.StringVar()
    self.choice_rubbing_marks[key] =  ['No', 'Yes']
    self.rubbing_marks_Type[key].set('') # set the default option
    self.Menu_rubbing_marks[key] = tk.OptionMenu(
        self.A_Frame_measure, 
        self.rubbing_marks_Type[key], *self.choice_rubbing_marks[key],
        command=self.show_rubbing_marks_borders
    )
    self.Menu_rubbing_marks[key].config(width=4)    
    self.Menu_rubbing_marks[key].grid_forget()
```